# Angular version updation: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I want to update my current project’s angular version to the latest angular version. But facing following error : **Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient**.

My current angular version is 4.4, as per latest angular version I would like to update to 8.2.
As per https://update.angular.io/ its not recommended to update multiple angular versions at a time so currently I am updating from 4.4 to 5.2 and then would move ahead.

I have followed the steps from https://update.angular.io/#4.4:5.2.

After that I removed/uninstalled 2 Angular2 specific packages as they were not supported in Angular5.

1. angular2-busy
2. angular2-uuid

Also I updated few peer dependencies and their respective dev dependencies

1. @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
2. @ngx-translate/core
3. codelyzer (Updated its dev dependency - tslint)

Now when I try to run “**ng serve**” command I am getting following errors:

```
ERROR in /Volumes/Work/Projects/src/app/readiumjs/readium_reader.d.ts (6,18): Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
ERROR in /Volumes/Work/Projects/src/app/readiumjs/readium_reader.d.ts (7,18): Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
ERROR in /Volumes/Work/Projects/src/lib/epub1.d.ts (14,18): Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
```

Here are my files:

**package.json -**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.11",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "array-unique": "^0.3.2",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "elasticlunr": "^0.9.5",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "normalizr": "^3.3.0",
    "readline": "^1.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.12",
    "sw-toolbox": "^3.6.0",
    "tether": "^1.4.3",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "web-animations-js": "2.2.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.11",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.0.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-sync": "^0.1.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-html-reporter": "^0.2.7",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.16",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "protractor-html-screenshot-reporter": "0.0.21",
    "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.5.0",
    "sw-precache": "^5.1.1",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "^5.0.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.7"
  }
```

Below are some parts of the code which I think is failing:

**readium_reader.d.ts (6,18) -**

```
declare function setBookTitle(bookId: string, bookTitle: string);
```

**main.js -**

```
function setBookTitle(_bookId, _bookTitle) {
  bookId = _bookId;
  bookTitle = _bookTitle;
}
```

**epubReadiumReaderComponent.ts -**

```
setBookTitle(bookId, bookName);
```

***Note:*** I searched for the answer for above issues but couldn’t get any proper solution for it.
Some of them asked to change the function name as its been overloading, but it couldn’t worked for me.

Comment: I am not sure. but did you try adding return type to the declared function like `declare function setBookTitle(bookId: string, bookTitle: string): void`

Comment: @Sumit Yes, I tried with return type **void** and as well as with **any**, but both didn't work for me.

Comment: it says `overload signature` did you check if there is any other function with the same name declared. This is usually caused because of it. The easy solution would be to wrap this export inside another namespace and then use it

Comment: @Sumit No, there are no other occurrences for the same. These are the only three occurrences for **setBookTitle** function name.